# Python code outputting fine until calculation

Tags: python

So, I have a set of data points to do a linear regression on, with most of the big calculations working smoothly.

```
from __future__ import division
data = [[0.0,0.0], [1.0,2.0], [2.0,4.0]]

#regression model
n = float(len(data))
sumx = 0.0
sumy = 0.0
sumxsquared = 0.0
sumxy = 0.0
rcoeff = 0.0
m = 0.0

print (n)

i=0

while (i < n):
  sumx += data[i][0]
  sumxsquared += (data[i][0])**2.0
  sumxy += data[i][0]*data[i][1]
  sumy += data[i][1]
  i += 1

print ("total x: " + str(sumx))
print ("total y: " + str(sumy))
print ("total xy: " + str(sumxy))
print ("total x squared: " + str(sumxsquared))
```

However, after I add the following code, my 'm' reads zero

```
m = ((sumy*sumxsquared-sumx*sumxy)/((n*sumxsquared)-sumx**2.0))

print ("m:" + str(m))
```

I'm struggling to find reasons why, could I please have some help?

Comment: obviously that expression is evaluating to 0. for that to happen, `sumy*sumsquared  == sumx*sumxy` you should print out the values of both of all of those and check by hand and then figure out what they were supposed to be.

Comment: Also a few things: you don't need to initialize `m` at the top if you arent going to increment it or use it in a function. Same thing for `rcoeff`.

In print statements, you can add a comma instead of manually converting objects into strings. 

don't write a `while` loop like that, when `for` loops are designed for that purpose.
ie:
`for(i in range(n)):`
instead of 
`i = 0 while(i < n): i+=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numerator of your expression

```
((sumy*sumxsquared-sumx*sumxy)/((n*sumxsquared)-sumx**2.0))
```

is `6*5 - 3*10`, which is `30 - 30` or zero, so of course the entire fraction evaluates to zero.

Note that your data is made of three points that are in a straight line (`(0,0)`, `(1,2)`, and `(2,4)`) and in addition that line goes through the origin, so many statistics based on these points will be zero.

Answer (score 0):

You are dividing 0 by 6 which is 0:

```
a=(sumy*sumxsquared)
b=(sumx*sumxy)
c=(n*sumxsquared)
d=(sumx**2.0)
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d)
m = (a-b)/(c-d)   
print ("m:" + str(m))
```

Output:

```
30.0
30.0
15.0
9.0
m:0.0
```